# How can I get nodemon working in VS Code with a ECMAScript module written in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon, ecmascript-2022

I'm writing a NodeJS (v18+) app in Typescript, one that will be deployed to an Azure App Service eventually.

I'm writing this as an ECMAScript module, so I can take advantage of newer features such as top-level await etc.

With the below config, I've got my application to build and run correctly standalone with such features seemingly without issue, however I'm struggling to be able to debug on-the-fly with nodemon.

I'm sure there's an issue with my config somewhere, but I don't know what

Here is my typescript.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",                       /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": ["ES2022"],                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    "module": "es2022",                       /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    "rootDir": "src",                         /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                /* Enable importing .json files. */
    "allowJs": false,                         /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    "outDir": "build",                        /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                    /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                      /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

and here's my package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.3.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.2",
    "@yarnpkg/sdks": "^3.0.0-rc.35",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "rimraf": "^4.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "yarn nodemon",
    "build": "yarn rimraf ./build && yarn tsc",
    "start": "node build/app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.0"
  }
}
```

My ```nodemon.json`` file contains:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts,json",
  "exec": "ts-node --inspect ./src/app.ts" 
}
```

Here's the output when I run `yarn debug`:

```
yarn nodemon --inspect src/app.ts
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node --inspect src/app.ts`
C:\my-app\.yarn\cache\arg-npm-4.1.3-1748b966a8-544af8dd3f.zip\node_modules\arg\index.js:88
                                                const err = new Error(`Unknown or unexpected option: ${originalArgName}`);
                                                            ^

Error: Unknown or unexpected option: --inspect
    at arg (C:\my-app\.yarn\cache\arg-npm-4.1.3-1748b966a8-544af8dd3f.zip\node_modules\arg\index.js:88:19)
    at parseArgv (C:\my-app\.yarn\__virtual__\ts-node-virtual-4e86653c50\0\cache\ts-node-npm-10.9.1-6c268be7f4-090adff130.zip\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:69:12)
    at main (C:\my-app\.yarn\__virtual__\ts-node-virtual-4e86653c50\0\cache\ts-node-npm-10.9.1-6c268be7f4-090adff130.zip\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\my-app\.yarn\__virtual__\ts-node-virtual-4e86653c50\0\cache\ts-node-npm-10.9.1-6c268be7f4-090adff130.zip\node_modules\ts-node\dist\bin.js:579:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at require$$0.Module._extensions..js (C:\my-app\.pnp.cjs:13083:33)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at require$$0.Module._load (C:\my-app\.pnp.cjs:12902:22)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29) {
  code: 'ARG_UNKNOWN_OPTION'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

If I remove the `--inspect` option from the command in `nodemon.json`, I get:

```
yarn nodemon
[nodemon] 2.0.20
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src\**\*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/app.ts`
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\my-app\src\app.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:79:11)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:121:38)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:81:20)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at load$1 (file:///C:/my-app/.pnp.loader.mjs:1455:12)
    at nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:605:26)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:22)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:64:26) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is my VSCode launch.json file - although right now I'm just trying to get nodemon to work on the command line first, before then thinking about getting it into the editor.

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug via Nodemon",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [ "debug" ],
      "runtimeExecutable": "yarn",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "type": "node",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }
  ]
}
```

This sort of config has worked for me with no issues before, but only with commonjs projects.

I've been trying all sorts of different combinations of ts-node/nodemon arguments to get this working, but I don't seem to have much success. Most of the solutions online seem to be to remove the `type: module` option from package.json and make it a commonjs module, but I don't want to do that here. I'd just like to be able to debug on the fly in vscode, with nodemon recompiling when there's a source-file change.

Answer (score 0):

So after searching online I altered my `nodemon.json` file to read

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": ".ts,.js",
  "ignore": [],
  "exec": "node --loader ts-node/esm ./src/app.ts"
}
```

and changed my `debug` script in my `package.json` to simply be `yarn nodemon`.

I then had issues where `ts-node` couldn't be found, despite being installed. In the end I disabled yarn's Plug & Play functionality by adding a `.yarnrc.yml` file which read: `nodeLinker: node-modules`, removed my existing `.yarn` folder, any `.pnp.` files and re-ran `yarn`, which seemed to have fixed things. Looks like this doesn't play nicely with yarn's Plug & Play.